# javascript powerpoint get slide number in browser

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js

i am using below code to show power point in web.
Now i need get current slide number of power point in Javascript.

`<iframe  src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=@ViewBag.Data"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

The property that you want is [Office.CoercionType.SlideRange.index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.coerciontype?view=word-js-preview). For an example of how to use it, look at this [PowerPoint add-in tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/powerpoint-tutorial#get-slide-metadata).

Comment: thanks, but i need get current slide number in browser. i am showing ppt in browser.